# C++ Windows Driver MSB3030 could not copy the file '' because it was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

VS2017, SDK/WDK, C++ project

we have a c++ solution (driver) that is shared across developers via Team Foundation Services - visualstudio.com (now called azure devops?).

When I perform a get latest source code, and want to rebuild the solution I get two MSB3030 errors:
"Could not copy the file "C:\path of my colleague his file" because it was not found."

I found it strange that I saw on one of the two errors a path of my colleague his pc. He works on C:\ I'm working on E:\

Unloading the project, I saw he path being set here:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToPackage Include="C:\path of my colleague\foo.xml" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
      <PackageRelativeDirectory>
      </PackageRelativeDirectory>
    </FilesToPackage>
```

We cannot get this **solution** to build because of the MSB3030. First we have to clean the specific projects individually, rebuild it, then build another project etc.. a few steps to perform manually in the correct order , trial and error, drinking coffee, throwing bananas to the pc and praying that a monkey outputs the code correctly.

Has anyone seen somehting similar regarding MSB3030 errors? 
On my pc I see the path of my colleague, but he doesn't see my path (strange!).

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(1699,5): error MSB3030:
>   Could not copy the file 'C:...'  because it was not found.

I've set the Any CPU to x64 because it doesn't make any sense for c++.

Comment: The only solution we have with v4 print driver to making successful builds is first cleaning the driver project, next building the driver project, and finally rebuilding the render-filter project.
Problem is not bound to pc as we have it on two pc's.
 i didn't have time to test your solution yet, but for now if we (re)build in this order it works. The v4 driver was created via VS17 File > New Project > .. wizard thing...

Answer (score 0):

> C++ Windows Driver MSB3030 could not copy the file '' because it was not found

The reason for this issue is that the path of the `ItemGroup` is an absolute path in the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToPackage Include="C:\path of my colleague\foo.xml" ...>
...
    </FilesToPackage>
</ItemGroup>
```

Regardless of whether your colleague has added this file to source control, when you pull the code from the TFS server to your local and put the code in a different local folder, the absolute path will bring you a lot of trouble, you need to manually check the code on the TFS server for this file and you need to modify the absolute path of this file in your project. But this problem will reappear after your colleague updates after you submit your code. Because **an absolute path cannot be assigned to two different paths** `C:\` and `E:\`.

To resolve this issue, you need to change the absolute path to a relative path in the source code. Generally, we prefer to add this file to the Solution/Project folder, then use the MSBuild Macros `$(SolutionDir)`/`$(ProjectDir)` to specify it.

Check [Common macros for build commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2017) for some more details.

Hope this helps.